# How can I write the items to UILabel from the array?

Tags: ios, swift

I am struggling with a problem since yesterday.

I have a data array which contains only string type and I want to pull them and write it inside to the UILabel. There is enough space and the font size is normal. But when I print to console it works fine but when I write more than one strings to UILabel, it gets the latest string from the array and assign it to UILabel.

Let me show you a quick example..

```
let array = ["Harry Potter","Lord of the Rings","Ghost Town"]
for i in array {
myLabel.text = "\(i)\n" 
} // I only get the Ghost Town into my UILabel and nothing else!
```

I have set the label line = 0 from Xcode UI and also added a code like the following:

```
myLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

But these haven't solved my problem. I wanted to ask this and thought maybe there is an easy solution. Thanks. Take care!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `joined()` function:

```
myLabel.text = "\(array.joined())\n"
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like" \n" does not help for line breaking. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Found a solution like \(array.joined(separator: "\n")

THAT WORKED. THANKS A LOT!